# Is there a Trac or Redmine host that allows you to install plugins?

Tags: hosting, trac, redmine

Google tells me that there are a fair few companies that offer hosted Trac and Redmine. So far I have tried [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/) who provide Trac hosting for free, but they don't allow plugins. I am prepared to pay for a managed solution, but we need it to have support for plugins, and it needs to be responsive when accessed from most places in the world (since we're an open source project).

We have investigated hosting it ourselves, but it's incredibly difficult to get good peering on cheap virtual servers, and we can't afford to go with fully-fledged dedicated hosting. We could try Geo-dispersed self-hosting on cheap servers, but we want to focus more on development than website administration.

Again, I can't emphasise enough my two requirements:

- Must support plugins
- Must be very responsive

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [DreamHost](http://dreamhost.com) - they have a One-Click installer for Trac and allow you to install Trac plugins. You also get Shell Access so you can run any advanced commands necessary for configure your Trac environment. We've been using DreamHost for SVN/Trac hosting for a couple of small projects and it's been consistently responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Trac plugins can do anything, and I mean *anything* that the Python interpreter is allowed to (I suspect Redmine is the same way). That includes, for example,

- running an eternal loop, sucking up CPU
- writing the disk full
- destroying the Trac database
- messing up the Trac environment in all imaginable ways
- etc.

Maybe you see a pattern here: it's much easier to manage Trac hosting if you don't allow plugins. Therefore, I wouldn't expect to see Trac hosting that allows plugins.